# VW Passat CC 2008 engine swap compatibility

Tags: engine, vw, passat, engine-swap

I have a 2008 VW Passat CC which the engine has given out. I want to replace the engine but am not sure what engine codes are compatible. The engine code currently on the car is CBA. I have sourced an engine with the code CBD but am not sure if this would be compatible

I have got onto VW directly by they refuse to tell me if the engines are compatible or not as they want to sell me a brand new one

Does anyone know if this would be compatible or how I would go about finding this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that CBAB and CBDB engines?  They are both EA189 engines and as such have identical engine blocks, cylinder head and camshafts.  They're both 2.0 Common Rail Diesel engines with 140bhp and they both appeared in 2008 Passats, Tiguans and Golfs.

I'm not sure what the difference between the engines is but suspect it may be to do with emissions control or fuel economy systems.  It may be something as simple as the alternator is different.  I know that this group of engines has three different shaped fuel filter housings for example.  It is most likely that the difference is an minor as this.

The facts are that the engine will fit on your existing engine mounts, will connect to your gearbox bell housing, will bolt onto your existing exhaust and inlet manifolds.  You may find that a couple of ancillary items such as the plug on the back of the alternator or some of the temperature sensors differ slightly but because you have your old, damaged engine, you can swap any different ancillary items over to the new engine.

Comment: About the engine code, im not too sure are the code I have is CBA091511, so am not 100% if it is CBAA or CBAB but it is registered as 140 and not 136 so I would believe its the CBAB and not the CBAA

Comment: I agree with Steve Matthews' observations. I'll add that *if* there are differences in the two engine's emissions control plumbing, then the replacement engine might not pass your local licensing authority's periodic emissions inspection and testing...if your local authority has such for diesel vehicles.